# Magento 1.9 - Store Hours of Operation not available for CMS

Tags: configuration, cms, cms-block

Under `Admin->System->Configuration->General`, there is a field called `Store Hours of Operation`.

Referencing to this field using `{{config path="general/store_information/hours"}}` in a static block outputs nothing, while other fields ouput correctly, such as `{{config path="general/store_information/phone"}}`.

If you click `Insert Variable` from the editor, you'll see other variables but not `Store Hours` either.

Any idea why `Store Hours` is hidden from CMS? How can I display it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to go to **System -> Permissions -> Variables** and **add new variable**

`general/store_information/hours` as ***allowed*** for it to work on frontend.

---

As to **why** it is like this, I guess they just forgot to add it in `app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php`:

> `$installer->getConnection()->insertMultiple(
>       $installer->getTable('admin/permission_variable'),
>       array(
>           array('variable_name' => 'trans_email/ident_support/name', 'is_allowed' => 1),
>           array('variable_name' => 'trans_email/ident_support/email','is_allowed' =>  1),
>           array('variable_name' => 'web/unsecure/base_url','is_allowed' =>  1),
>           array('variable_name' => 'web/secure/base_url','is_allowed' =>  1),
>           array('variable_name' => 'trans_email/ident_general/name','is_allowed' =>  1),
>           array('variable_name' => 'trans_email/ident_general/email', 'is_allowed' => 1),
>           array('variable_name' => 'trans_email/ident_sales/name','is_allowed' =>  1),
>           array('variable_name' => 'trans_email/ident_sales/email','is_allowed' =>  1),
>           array('variable_name' => 'trans_email/ident_custom1/name','is_allowed' =>  1),
>           array('variable_name' => 'trans_email/ident_custom1/email','is_allowed' =>  1),
>           array('variable_name' => 'trans_email/ident_custom2/name','is_allowed' =>  1),
>           array('variable_name' => 'trans_email/ident_custom2/email','is_allowed' =>  1),
>           array('variable_name' => 'general/store_information/name', 'is_allowed' => 1),
>           array('variable_name' => 'general/store_information/phone','is_allowed'  => 1),
>           array('variable_name' => 'general/store_information/address', 'is_allowed' => 1),
>       )
>   );`